# call.enqueue not working for two retrofit calls in same class

Tags: android, retrofit2

Hello I am new to Android. I am trying to call and save two API from same class and place both data from those API into same `RecyclerView`.
The first  retrofit  is working but in the second retrofit call there is problem. 
The code is as below for second retrofit

```
private void callRetrofitListData(){
    pariyojanaInterfaces = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(PariyojanaInterface.class);
    Log.e("pariyojanaInterfaces", String.valueOf(pariyojanaInterfaces));
    Call<List<Data>> call = pariyojanaInterfaces.getData(memberId);
    Log.e("urll",call.request().toString())
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Data>> call, Response<List<Data>> response) {

            Log.e("check","chekc");

            datas = (List<Data>) response.body();

            itemListAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), datas);
            rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
            rv.setAdapter(itemListAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Data>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

In this case the debugger is not going inside this function

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Data>>()
```

and says No such instance field: 'PariyojanaInterfaces'.

The `PariyojanaInterface` is shown below:

```
public interface PariyojanaInterface {
    @POST("projectBudget/pariyojanaListForMobile")
    Call<List<Data>> getData(@Query("memberId") int memberId);
}
```

Can somebody please help me solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add @FormUrlEncoded in your interface before @POST() line
and

in POST method we use **@FIELD** instead of **@QUERY**

Comment: @Abhisek
thnx for your quick response but it still is not working In the line,
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DataList>>() it says
No such instance field: 'pariyojanaInterfaces'   
No such instance field: 'memberId'